# How do I Render a Drupal User Profile using api calls?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm doing this to render a node and returning the output to an AJAX call and displaying a node inline on a page:

```
$node = node_load($nid);
$node_view = node_view($node);
echo drupal_render($node_view);
```

I need to be able to do the same things for a user profile...is it similar?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's pretty similar, you can use the following functions:

```
$account = user_load($uid);
$account_view = user_view($account);
echo drupal_render($account_view);
```

**EDIT**

I changed the variable name to use `$account` instead of `$user`, just to eliminate the possibility of overwriting the global `$user` variable.

Answer (score 3):

The [Entity API](http://drupal.org/project/entity) module provide a generic function to render any entity: `entity_view()` that can also be used. For a user entity this should produce the same results than [`user_view()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.module/function/user_view/7).

```
$account = user_load($uid);
$account_view = entity_view('user', $account);
echo drupal_render($account_view);
```